# Always display a callout in react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to find a way to always display a `<Callout />` or a `<Marker />` description/title without the need of clicking on the title.

This code will only display the title and description when the marker is clicked:

```
import { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
<MapView
  region={this.state.region}
  onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
>
  {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
    <Marker
      coordinate={marker.latlng}
      title={marker.title}
      description={marker.description}
    />
  ))}
</MapView>
```

So, is there a way of always showing it?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?